# Homeomorphisms which switch 2 points

Tags: general-topology, homogeneous-spaces

Let $X$ be a space and suppose:

*For every two points $x,y\in X$ there is a homeomorphism $h$ that maps $X$ onto itself and such that $h(x)=y$ and $h(y)=x$.*

Is there a name for  this property?

Obviously $X$ is homogeneous. Does every homogeneous space have this property?  If not, are there some classes of homogeneous spaces which have the property?  For instance does every homogeneous compact connected metric space?

Comment: Well, 2-transitivity of the group of homeomorphisms of $X$ implies this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such spaces are called *bi-homogeneous* (or perhaps *bihomogeneous*).

An example of a homogeneous space which is not bi-homogeneous is the long-line without the initial point (*i.e.*, $X = ( \omega_1 \times [0,1) ) \setminus \{ ( 0 , 0 ) \}$).  It is fairly easy to show that $X$ is homoegeneous, but since all homeomorphisms $X \to X$ are order-preserving it cannot be bi-homogeneous.

Many of the homogeneous spaces you encounter "in the wild" will be bi-homogeneous, but there doesn't appear to be many classes of topological spaces where homogeneity implies bi-homogeneity. One class of spaces for which this implication is (non-vacuously) true is the class of topological groups.

Homogeneous but not bi-homogeneous continua have been constructed. For one (and I believe the first) example see

- *Kuperberg, Krystyna*, [**On the bihomogeneity problem of Knaster**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2001594), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 321, No. 1, 129-143 (1990). [ZBL0707.54025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0707.54025).

Comment: Thank you for that.   By the way, I do think bi-homogeneity is true in homogeneous manifolds.

Comment: @ForeverMozart Well, the space $X$ in my answer is a connected homogeneous non-bi-homogeneous manifold without boundary (of dimension $1$).

Comment: I think you are both right, because of the lack of agreement as to whether to require paracompactness in the definition of a manifold.